# How can I pass multiple arguments to Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension?

Tags: powershell, azure

The Azure Cmdlet for adding a Custom Script Extension to a VM named [Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.compute/v1.3.4/set-azurermvmcustomscriptextension) has an `-Argument` switch, which states that it accepts a string, but no example of how this is implemented. While it says it can accept multiple arguments, it appears to be for a single argument.

I need to pass multiple arguments, but can't find the correct syntax to do so.

Example:

```
$arg1 = "mysitename"
$arg2 = "c:/mydirectorytocreate"

-Argument "$arg1,$arg2"
```

How do I pass multiple arguments to [Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.compute/v1.3.4/set-azurermvmcustomscriptextension) so I can pass these values to the actual script that needs these values (ex. passing an IIS Site Name and a Directory Path as two separate values).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example of multiple arguments in use from [this blog](http://www.codeisahighway.com/set-azurevmcustomscriptextension-multiple-extensions-per-handler-not-supported/):

> ```
> Set-AzureVMCustomScriptExtension -VM $x -ContainerName 'test' -FileName 'script1.ps1','script2.ps1','script3.ps1' -Run 'script1.ps1' -Argument 'arg1 arg2' 
>       | Update-AzureVM
> ```

If this code snipett actually works then it means you need to **pass a space delimited string** for your arguments. Just make sure you keep your double quotes so the variables expand properly.

Comment: That did it. In the end I had "$arg1 $arg2" in double quotes. Important to note that I declare the values of $arg1 and $arg2 as variables so I don't have to worry about quoting a string such as a path within the argument

Comment: See here for spaces in arguments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355827/execute-dsc-file-with-set-azuremrmvmcustomscriptextension

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a difference between the ASM (classic) and ARM version of this cmdlet but for me, I had to do it thus (parameters missing for clarity):

```
$arguments = "-arg1 'foo' -arg2 'bar' -arg3 'cat'"

Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension `
    -Argument $Arguments `
    -Run "SomeScript.ps1"
```

SomeScript.ps1 would look something like:

```
param
(
    [string]$arg1,
    [string]$arg2,
    [string]$arg3
)

function SomeFunction
{
    Write-Host $arg1
    Write-Host $arg2
    Write-Host $arg3

    #Do something here...
}
SomeFunction -arg1 $arg1 -arg2 $arg2 -arg3 $arg3 #Call the function from within SomeScript.ps1
```

If you could actually see the output of Write-Host when run from a Custom Script Extension, it would result in an output of :

```
foo
bar
cat
```

HTH.

Comment: The "params" should be param at the beginning of the file and also the params section in the function body shouldn't be there.

Comment: @AmoghNatu Thanks. Updated.